# blender image showing transparent on cube

Tags: rendering, image

[image: transparent cube]

As I place an image texture onto a cube, the cube renders transparent, you know those black & white checkerboards.

[image: compositor tab]

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your "Compositor" tab?

Comment: shows fine on preview but not when rendered

Comment: new to blender, tried all tutorials, result same

Comment: Could you send the blend file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi. Please don't ask the same question twice. If you need to add information to your question you can use the edit link below the original question.